# Does java.sql.Timestamp provide nanosecond precision that is useful?

Tags: java, timestamp

I ran a simple test to create a million time objects and tested the following

```
 int nano = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()).getNanos();
 if((nano & 0x00000000003F) != 0x0) {
    System.out.println("Nano from timestamp : " +  nano);
 }
```

Nothing was output, implying that the last least significant 6 digits were all zeros. So, does Timestamp merely depend on the value as returned from System.currentTimeMillis() and just multiply it with 1000000?

Is Timestamp useful with nanosecond precision?  In the current case, since I am not getting any non-zero value, it implies that the precision is just reduced to milliseconds (and not nanoseconds).

So what's the benefit of using Timestamp?

Comment: A `java.util.Date.getTime()` only has milliseconds, so you can't get nanos this way.

Answer (score 4):

The type [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) has nanosecond precision using a separate field, as documented:

> Note: This type is a composite of a `java.util.Date` and a separate
> nanoseconds value. Only integral seconds are stored in the
> `java.util.Date` component. The fractional seconds - the `nanos` - are
> separate.

You are setting the timestamp value using [`java.util.Date.getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--), which provides only millisecond precision: *"Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object."*; the subsecond value of that millisecond value is stored in the nanos field, in other words, the submillisecond value of nanos is zero this way.

If you want to use the nanosecond precision, you need to set and get the nanos separately (using [`setNanos`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#setNanos-int-) and [`getNanos`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getNanos--)), or you need to construct it from a type that does have nanosecond precision (`java.time.LocalDateTime`) using [`Timestamp.valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDateTime-).

Given that nanos stores all of the fractional seconds, using `setNanos` has some caveats, see also some of the answers to [java.sql.Timestamp way of storing NanoSeconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839411/java-sql-timestamp-way-of-storing-nanoseconds)

This said, you will only get benefit from this nanosecond precision if the database you use actually supports it. For example, I maintain the JDBC driver for Firebird, and Firebird supports only 100 microsecond precision, not nanosecond precision; and PostgreSQL, for example, supports microsecond precision.